# Chance of finding a tree in a sample area

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have 83 trees appearing over 24 quadrats (a quadrat being a 10m x 10m sample area => 2400m^2 total area), what's the chance of finding a tree in a sample area? What's the chance of finding a tree per m^2?

Comment: What information do you have about the distribution of the trees?

Comment: Nothing beyond what's stated in the question; 83 trees appear over 24 quadrats. I need to find the frequency, quoted as "chance of finding a species in the sample area". Example given to me is: 10 occurences in 20 quadrats => a frequency of 50%. From which I would assume the frequency is 346%, if not for the "chance of finding" in the definition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given no more information, the chance of a particular tree being in a given quadrat is $\frac 1{24}$. Therefore the chance of the tree not being in the quadrat is $\frac {23}{24}$. Lacking any other information, we assume that the placement of the trees is independent (a dubious assumption, since trees tend to cluster because of how they propagate). Therefore the chance of our quadrat not having any of the 83 trees would be $\left(\frac {23}{24}\right)^{83}$.

And thus the probability that our quadrat does have a tree in it is $$1 -\left(\frac {23}{24}\right)^{83}$$

The calculation for sample sizes of $1\; m^2$ is similar.

Comment: Thanks for the response! While I don't need the answer, would I, therefore, be correct to calculate the probability 1 m^2 does contain a tree through 1 - (2399/2400)^83? Also, so I can read up on it, is there a name for the general form of the formula?

Comment: Yes, that is the probability for the $m^2$ problem. I know of no name. It is just a general principle of probability that sometimes it is easier to directly calculate $P(\lnot A)$ than it is to calculate $P(A)$. Because $A$ and $\lnot A$ are mutually exclusive and include all possibilities, $P(A) + P(\lnot A) = 1$. So if you can calculate one, you can get the other by subtraction.